# How can I put page through printer without cartridge?

Tags: printing, printer

It might sound like a strange question, but I noticed that my printer is folding paper. So I would like diagnose it, whether it's because of cartridge or the problem is somewhere else.

If I could put paper through printer without cartridge inside, and it still would be folded then it would clearly be the problem with printer itself.

Printer is HP M125nw. Basically I would like to make sure, that folding is not because of cartridge.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you suspect that the cartridge is causing paper to fold?

Comment: @Karan I'm not, but HP service is suspecting it. Their original cartridges have price 3.5 times higher than replacements. I mean, three original cartridges would be worth new printer.

Comment: Yes, consumables is how they all gouge customers and make money.

Comment: @Karan As much as we love to think that, it's not true (at least not completely ;) ). The cost of producing/providing ink has stayed roughly the same for years, but the cost of producing a printer (especially low-end ones) has gone down dramatically. If you bought a printer for $400 and spent $80 to replace the cartridges 10 years ago, you'd feel OK about it.  For a similarly-featured printer today you may only spend $80 for the printer, but the cartridges would still be $80, making it seem like a rip-off.

Comment: @Karan Mind you, this doesn't mean some printer manufacturers aren't taking advantage of this, at least a little.. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 If cost of producing ink stayed same for years, why replacement supplies are much, much cheaper and they can print equal amount of pages? There's something wrong with your explaination.

Comment: @stil Replacement carts. for a printer with equivalent feature sets are not much cheaper than they used to be, at least not in my experience. Cheap 3rd party ink/toner replacements were cheaper than OEM back 10 years ago too. ;)  "Replacement" does not automatically equal "3rd party".

Answer (score 2):

It **cannot possibly** be the ink cartridges.

It's a Laser Printer - the print heads don't go anywhere near the paper path.
Think of it like offset litho.
Ink > roller > paper

The paper path may be 180˚ away from the initial ink [toner] transfer

See Wikipedia - [Laser printing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_printing)

Or, if you really need to see the parallel - [Offset Lithography [printing]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_printing)

Comment: That's a very good argument. I'll reach HP again and try to use all my points to fight them ;]

Comment: @Tetsujin I disagree. The HP M125nw is a mono printer. Most mono printers have the drum (photoreceptor) inside the toner cartridge, and the paper will indeed go past the drum, as that is the roller that accepts the toner before it goes onto the paper. Why not try another cartridge to see if that fixes the problem?

Answer (score 1):

looking at images of this printer, it doesn't look like there is a manual paper feed button.

Your best bet is to remove the cartridges one by one and do a print.  First remove black and do a print, then remove another and replace black and print again etc...  The printer may or may not allow this.

The alternative is to simply print a blank document.  If there is no need for the print head to be lowered, it won't crumple the paper.

It won't be down to the type of ink in the cartridge... it may give you poor print performance, but the ink won't jump out of the cartridge, screw up your page and then go back into the cartridge.

It won't be the dimensions of the cartridge either - if it was too big, it wouldn't fit in the printer - or would at least smear ink across the page where it over-contacted if the cartridge was only too big by a mm or two..

I highly doubt that it is the cartridges that are chewing up your paper.  If I were you, I'd call them back and tell them you've tried original cartridges and it didn't work.

Comment: Exactly. Non-original cartriges may affect your printing quality, but it's hard to find one which has wrong physical dimensions.

Comment: It's still folded when I print blank page, but how can we be sure that print head is not involved? It was folding with original cartridge too, but I don't have it anymore.

Comment: it could be the head... it could be the rollers/feeder - but this is very difficult to diagnose.  By getting the same results with your older original cartridges, you've proven its not the ink/cartridge and clearly a warranty job.